# React componentDidUpdate() does not fire

Tags: reactjs

I have an react app with primereact installed and I am using primereact/captcha.

Maybe I have misunderstood something, but isn't the following code supposed to work (**console.log('Child component did update')**)?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Captcha } from 'primereact/captcha';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ParentComponent/>
    </div>
  );
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate () {
        console.log('Child component did update');
    }
    render() {
        return (<h2>Child component</h2>);
    }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            captchaSovled: false,
            key : Math.random()
        }
    }
    render() {
        let output;
        if (this.state.captchaSolved) {
            output = <Child key={this.state.key} />;
        } else {
            output =<Captcha siteKey="xxxxxxx" onResponse={() => this.setState({ key : Math.random(), captchaSolved: true })} />
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Parent component</h1>
                {output}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

In your code, the `Child` component is mounted after `captchaSolved` state is set, therefore only `componentDidMount` is fired on `Child` component.

Comment: I have the key prop <Child key={this.state.key} />

Comment: Initially, your `captchaSolved` state is `false`, the component tree is: `ParentComponent` -> `Captcha`. At this point the `Child` component is not mounted yet. `ParentComponent` will trigger its own `componentDidMount` (and `Captcha` component as well). After captcha is set, component tree become `ParentComponent` -> `Child`, at this point, `componentDidMount` will be called on `Child`, and `componentDidUpdate` will be called on `ParentComponent`. The fact that you have key or other props passed to your `Child` component won't affect this behaviour.

Comment: Also `key` is kind of a special thing, it's not actually a prop, but it helps React knows whether they should perform update or mount a new component after re-render. [See React keys doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate` is fired, if there is any change in the `state` or `props`. As of your component `child`:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate () {
        console.log('Child component did update');
    }
    render() {
        return (<h2>Child component</h2>);
    }
}
```

There is no `state` or `props` which are changing, that's why `componentDidUpdate` never get's invoked.

Comment: What about the key prop ? <Child key={this.state.key} />;

Comment: That is just for `React` itself for minimal updates in DOM. That's not a prop.